# The Case of the Elementary Math

Tags: pattern, lateral-thinking

Due to many complaints about my code problem being to unoriginal, I have decided to write another problem based off the same idea, and a simple story.

Now Sherlock and Watson were solving a case of Miranda White. She was a teacher at the local middle school, but was notorious for being tricky and catching her students off guard. She was found dead at the bottom of the stairs, seeming to have tripped over something, but it was not known what.

Holmes found himself in the teachers classroom, seeing if there was any clues to help guide him on his quest to find the murderer. On the blackboard he found a few simply wrong math equations.

> 3+90+53+92+42=3+1
>   22+7=50
>   7+8+4+3+92+42=102+1
>   59+8+9+42+75+18+22+74+33+2+75=?

Who was the killer and how did Sherlock Holmes know?
It's elementary my fellow puzzlers...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The numbers represent the element with that atomic number, and addition represents string concatenation. The right sides of the equations are the element names spelled out in full, and the left sides are element abbreviations. So:

```
LiThIUMo = Lithium + [one letter]
TiN = Tin
NOBeLiUMo = Nobelium + [one letter]
```

Which makes the answer:

```
PrOFMoReArTiWAsHeRe
```